# How can I determine parentage of Thomas McCubbin (McCubbins) who died ca1875 in Missouri?

Tags: records, census-records, death-records, proof

Thomas McCubbn (wife Emily) was my gg grandfather.

Thomas died late 1875 or early 1876 in Warrensburg MIssouri (his son said Thomas died an early age).

It is believed this Thomas McCubbn is the son of David McCubbin & Louisa Jane Gum.

How would I set out to verify Thomas McCubbn's parents?

Assistance is much appreciated; it is the one and only missing link in my McCubbin genealogy.

Comment: It would be helpful if as part of your question, you share how you know that Thomas died "late in 1875 or early 1876" at the place reported. Also, why "it is believed" that he is the son of David and Louisa; and of course, the sources of information you have about David and Louisa. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tree on [FamilySearch](http://familysearch.org) that may be of interest to you. Obviously you need to check the facts here, but that should help get you started. The [tree](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.2.1/MWQS-RXL) does not give Thomas's death, but it does list some information about his parents and his siblings.

I found the tree by guessing at some ages and searching for Luisa Gum, since I figured that name may not be as mangled as McCubbins when being written down.